# jQuery Fade on Hover Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade, jquery-hover

I'm trying to make an image have a white overlay on mouse hover. It seems  to work on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EqH4H/, but not on my local website. The image just stays the same not does not fade.

This is my HTML code;

```
<div id="masonry_container" >

<div class="masonry_item">
<a href="http://storyville.jonmarkoff.com/storyvillewp"target="_blank">
<img src="images/storyville_home.png" alt="Storyville Entertainment"/>
<h3>Storyville Entertainment</h3>
<p>Development. jQuery hover effects.</p>
</a>
</div><!--masonry_item-->

</div>
```

CSS;

```
#masonry_container {
margin:0 auto 50px auto;
width:100%;
position:relative;
z-index:2001;
}

.masonry_item {
width:300px;
padding:20px;
}

.masonry_item:hover{ 
outline:1px solid white;
}

#masonry_container img {
width:100%;
background:white;
}
```

JS;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#masonry_container img").hover(
function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
},
function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
});
});
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: any error in the browser console also whether the elements are loaded dynamically

Comment: Are you importing jquery library on local website??

Comment: on hover of the image which element do you want to fade... the image only or any other element also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8nxB9/2/ it seems to work.

Comment: There were errors in the console, so I deleted the codes in my JS file that caused the errors, and now it works. Although I don't understand why they cause those errors, because they were working fine until before I added the hover effect. Thanks everybody anyway.